# Search Button in DataGridview

Tags: c#, database, datagridview

I'm coding a search Button for search row in dataGridview and my code is below:

```
protected void searchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataAdapter se = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Manu Where ArticleName like +'%" + textBox.Text + "%'", con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    se.Fill(ds);
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Error message:

> Additional information: Both `DataSource` and `DataSourceID` are defined on `GridView1`.  Remove one definition.

Comment: I think you really need to give google a try. This is the first link on my search: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/255064/Both-DataSource-and-DataSourceID-are-defined-on-Gr

Comment: I followed the instruction from your source and the search button worked, however, the other button such as add or delete row is not work anymore because there's no DataSource ID to display the gridView.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this 
This just make a button and under click event do this or you can also implement this in text_changed event of any textbox :)

```
string searchValue = textBox1.Text;

    dgvProjects.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
    try
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvProjects.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Cells[2].Value.ToString().Equals(searchValue))
            {
                row.Selected = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
    }
```